# how do i use the awk command properly

Tags: awk

I am a starter. I have a below file in which there are 4 columns; separated with pipe sign.

```
test.unl
XCS|10|20|20200505|
AWX|20|10|20200606|
WSX|20|10|20200517|
RFV|20|10|20200520|
TGB|10|20|20200609|
```

I need to write a command, if column 2 is 10 and column 3 is 20 then subtract the current date from last column, if the difference between dates is greater than 30, print the whole line in a file.

I am running the below command and it is giving me error.

```
more testfile.unl | awk -F '|' '{if(($2==10 && $3==20) && (((date -d "now" +%s)-(date -d "print$4" +%s)/86400))>>30) print$0}' >> File2.unl
```

Following are the errors i am receiving upon running the command:

```
awk: {if(($2==10 && $3==20) && ((date -d "print$4" +%s)-(date -d "now" +%s)/86400)>>30) print$0}
awk:                                                ^ syntax error
awk: {if(($2==10 && $3==20) && ((date -d "print$4" +%s)-(date -d "now" +%s)/86400)>>30) print$0}
awk:                                                   ^ syntax error
awk: {if(($2==10 && $3==20) && ((date -d "print$4" +%s)-(date -d "now" +%s)/86400)>>30) print$0}
awk:                                                                    ^ syntax error
awk: {if(($2==10 && $3==20) && ((date -d "print$4" +%s)-(date -d "now" +%s)/86400)>>30) print$0}
awk:                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: {if(($2==10 && $3==20) && ((date -d "print$4" +%s)-(date -d "now" +%s)/86400)>>30) print$0}
awk:                                                                        ^ unterminated regexp
```

Looking forward to your help, thanks!

Comment: Awk is an entire programming language. Basic usage is available in the man page (`man awk`) but a decent tutorial is a bit much for a stack overflow answer

Comment: @sorpigal, yes it would be too lengthy to be explained here. Could you pls help me in applying the correct syntax to the logic i have written?

Comment: I do not know awk, but it seems like you are asking for something like this: `cat testfile.unl | awk -F '|' '$2 == 10 && $3 == 20 { OFS="|" ; ( "date +%s" | getline now ) ; print $1, $2, $3, $4 - now  }'` or perhaps `| awk -F '|' '$2 == 10 && $3 == 20 { OFS="|" ; ( "date +%s" | getline now ) ; if ( $4 - now > 30 ) print }'`

Comment: @sorpigal, Dear I tried your first command, seems it triggers the first condition but the condition of time is not met ( the date has to be older than 30 days). Output came out to be following  ----> XCS|10|20|-1571590289
TGB|10|20|-1571590185

Comment: @RaviSaroch, didnt work. What is the difference between my command and your command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Using `systime` function of `awk` rather than using `date` shell command try following please.

```
awk -v thres="30" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
  current_time=systime()
}
$2 == 10 && $3 == 20{
  line_time=mktime(substr($4,1,4)" "substr($4,7,2)" "substr($4,5,2) " 00 00 00")
  if((current_time-line_time)/86400 > thres){  print }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** while starting `awk` program and mentioning variable `thres` as `30` threshold value posted by OP, could be changed as per need too. Variable in `BEGIN` section `current_time` which has current system's time in box. In main program, first checking condition if 2nd field is 10 and 3rd field is 20 then move further in current line else go to next line. 
 Getting 4th field and then using `mktime` to change 4th field to epoch time. Then substituting current time with line's time with dividing it with `86400` to convert it to days then checking if its value is greater than threshold then printing current line.

Comment: I believe this will do the job the OP wanted, but note that there's no need to call out to `date` for the current epoch.

Comment: Dear @RavinderSingh13, it worked. Could you pls explain the line ->>>line_time=mktime(substr($4,1,4)" "substr($4,7,2)" "substr($4,5,2) " 00 00 00")

Comment: @osia6028, Glad that it helped you, this lines means---> `on current line's 4th field taking sub-string 1st from 1st to 4th character(which has year in it), then taking 7th and 9th character and then creating sub-string which takes 5th and 6th character from current line` why we are doing this because mktime needs format of yyyy dd mm so basically making 4th field in that format to get epoch time. Kindly do lemme know in caseof any more queries here.

Comment: Dear @RavinderSingh13, many thanks. I get it now. Stay Safe, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it further, I think you may be trying to ask for lines where $2 == 10 and $3 == 20 and the date represented by the 4th column is more than 30 days from now.

If so this probably does the job:

```
 awk -F '|' '$2 == 10 && $3 == 20 { t = mktime(substr($1, 0, 4) " " substr($4, 5, 2) " " substr($4, 7, 2) " 0 0 0") ; now = systime() ; if ( ( (t - now) / 86400) > 30 ) print }'
```

But, again,  don't really know awk.

Comment: "Subtract the current date from the last column" seems unlikely to be correct unless you are projecting in to the future. Using `now - t` seems more likely to be correct, but it isn't what was asked for.

Comment: I tried using but it didn't give me the required output, more testfile.unl |  awk -F '|' '$2 == 10 && $3 == 20 { t = mktime(substr($1, 0, 4) " " substr($4, 5, 2) " " substr($4,
7, 2) " 0 0 0") ; now = systime() ; if ( ( (now - t) / 86400) > 30 ) print }'  
                                             
XCS|10|20|20200505|                                                                                                         
TGB|10|20|20200609| , Thank you though for trying :)

Comment: @osia6028: to get the output you expect reverse the t and now vars in the subtraction, like I said in my comment.